# Computer suddently slow after a blue screen

Tags: windows-7, laptop, freeze, performance

My computer was fine until I had a Blue Screen `0x0000007A`.

Right after that happen, I did a full recovery backup with the Acer tool that they give with the laptop cause I wanted to reformat for a long time. Now the drivers are all up to date and Windows 7 x64 up to date.

But since the blue screen, my computer is so slow, it takes like 30 minutes to reboot. And it keeps freezing like 20 secs randomly(not the mouse, only the program stops responding).

I thought it was the RAM, but I did run `memtest86` and I had no error.
What it could be? The HDD?

The weird thing is that it takes so much time to boot and that it's not slow when when it's fully started

The laptop is an Acer Aspire 8940g.

Comment: What happens when you run it on battery?

Comment: Overheating? There's a tool called "Speccy" that may show you the temperature.

Comment: @DanH Never tried, my dad let it plugged and on all day. I'm gonna take a look what happens unplugged. Do you think that a dead battery could cause this? Thank you

Comment: @pjc50 I thought it would shut down the computer if it would be overheating. And the problem happens even at the first boot after hours off. I'm gonna clean it inside and see if it makes a difference. thank you

Comment: @Marc: Have you tried running in safe mode? If it does the same thing then I would suspect the hard drive is failing.

Comment: My Sony got to where it wouldn't run for 2 minutes on the adapter, apparently because the battery overcharge detector was tripping.  Running it on battery worked fine, though, and once it went through one discharge/recharge cycle it was happy again.

Comment: download a tool like [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) and check the S.M.A.R.T. data for your hard drive - it may be failing

Comment: @DanH I tried it with the battery and my computer is not happy again lol.

Comment: OK, it was worth a shot.

Comment: Yeah thank you. It goes well now when i'm in Windows all loaded. But it takes like 30-40 minutes to boot.

Comment: @Nate Koppenhaver The report for my hdd is bad, i'm gonna change it. You can write it as an answer and I will give you the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes me think that your HDD may be bad. Download a tool such as [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) and check the S.M.A.R.T. data.

Answer (score 1):

Does Windows offer to report your error a short time after you start the computer?  After a BSoD, Windows collects data about the crash (hence the slowness) then offers to send it for analysis.  After sending the data, Microsoft returns solutions for known problems, often in the form of a software or driver update.  I have fixed numerous crash issues by using the "Report this error" feature.